# Vertical UIToolBar and also its UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

In my application i have one UIToolBar. When in portrait mode this toolbar is on top and is horizontal, but when the device is rotated this toolbar should be converted to vertical toolbar and should be place on left side. Also its subviews i.e 5 UIBarButtonItems should also be placed accordingly.

Does any one know the solution for this ?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570940/how-can-i-make-a-vertical-uitoolbar) for reference, But my tool bar should align itself according to the orientation. I am using iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in vertical menu feature (yet). There are 2 parts in your question:

Vertical **UIToolbar**:

You may restrict the device orientation and the toolbar will remain at the same location

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

(this will affect all views)

Or you can listen for orientation changes and rotate your toolbar accordingly using its transform property, e.g.

```
toolbar.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI/2);
```

Rotated **UIBarButtonItem**:

If you have rotated the toolbar (case 2 above), items will rotate too.
If not, you need to rotate your items. Several post shows how to deal with the fact that as UIBarButtonItem does not extend UIView, it has no transform property ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115417/rotate-uibarbuttonitem)). In the end you will have again to listen for orientation changes and rotate the subviews of your toolbar, e.g.

```
for (UIView *view in toolbar.subviews) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI/2);
}
```

Of course apply the rotation related to your orientation (M_PI/2 or -M_PI/2).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, so I subclassed `UIToolbar` and made it into exactly what I wanted it to be.
Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/fennelouski/NKFToolbar